# Simple Bread Crumbs Nav Links (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

My bread crumbs navlink scripts stopped working when I upgraded my database queries to PDO. I tried adapting it to PDO, then tried a couple new scripts, but they all have problems. So I think I need to just start from scratch.

The three key fields in my tables are URL, Parent and Title:

```
URL | Parent | Title
World | (NULL) | Our World
South-America | World | South America
Venezuela | South-America | Revolutionary Nation
Maria-Lionza | Venezuela | Maria Lionza
```

So if I visit the URL MySite/World/Maria-Lionza (page title "Maria Lionza"), I would like to see bread crumbs navigation links that display each segment's **Title**, though linked to the appropriate **URL**, like this:

```
World > South America > Venezuela > Maria Lionza
```

But the links would point to

```
MySite/World > MySite/World/South-America > MySite/World/Venezuela > MySite/World/Maria-Lionza
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that? I've figured out two or three amateurish ways of doing it, but they require a lot of extra tweaking and manipulation for each table. I'd like to duplicate my original script, which automatically displayed the entire hierarchy, from child to great-great grandparent.

Answer (score 0):

following example use [explode](http://php.net/explode) function to break up the URL, following the domain name add into array, separating it at each forward-slash.

```
$crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
        echo ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that script would work if the URL looked like this: MySite/World/South-America/Venezuela/Maria-Lionza. But if my URL is MySite/World/Maria-Lionza, then it won't display the intermediate segments (e.g. South-America, Venezuela).

P.S. It is a cool script, though, and I think I may have already found another use for it. ;)